# Google script to allow selecting only 1 checkbox per row and 3 checkboxes per column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, calculated-columns

I want to make a Google Script on the following [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_a6jA01Sz0bjTvQXh_S47qTFXfb0qV8KlTXgOGr6nU/) to allow only 1 checkbox selection per row, and 3 checkboxes selected per column as maximum, as described [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3UPP.png).

If 2 checkboxes are selected on the same row, a pop-up window should be displayed, saying "Please select only 1 checkbox per row", and the last edit should be set to FALSE. Same if more than 3 checkboxes per column are selected (pop-up windows saying "This column has already 3 selections, please choose a different column", and set to FALSE the last edit).

Comment: You can start with the `.getRange()` function [App Script get range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function imposes the restriction of only one check per row and 3 checks per column.  You have to provide the arrayrange parameter A1Notation string and the sheet name.  If you exceed the limits the last checkbox is returned to false and you get a warning in the format of a toast.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='You provide sheet name') {
    const mcpr=1;
    const mcpc=3;
    const arrayrange='A1:C10';//You provide A1Notation range string
    const arg=sh.getRange(arrayrange);
    const avs=arg.getValues();
    const ulr=arg.getRow();
    const ulc=arg.getColumn();
    const lrr=ulr+arg.getHeight()-1;
    const lrc=ulc+arg.getWidth()-1;   
    if(e.range.columnStart<=lrc && e.range.rowStart<=lrr && e.value=="TRUE") {
      let rc=avs[e.range.rowStart-ulr].filter(function(e){return e;}).reduce(function(a,v){ if(v){return a+1;} },0);
      if(rc>mcpr){e.range.setValue("FALSE");e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr);};
      let cc=avs.map(function(r,i){return r[e.range.columnStart-ulc];}).filter(function(e){return e}).reduce(function(a,v){if(v){return a+1;}},0);
      if(cc>mcpc){e.range.setValue('FALSE');e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc);};          
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

[Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[onEdit Event Block](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Your specific case:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1') {
    const mcpr=1;
    const mcpc=3;
    const arrayrange='D3:AC7';
    const arg=sh.getRange(arrayrange);
    const avs=arg.getValues();
    const ulr=arg.getRow();
    const ulc=arg.getColumn();
    const lrr=ulr+arg.getHeight()-1;
    const lrc=ulc+arg.getWidth()-1;   
    if(e.range.columnStart<=lrc && e.range.rowStart<=lrr && e.value=="TRUE") {
      let rc=avs[e.range.rowStart-ulr].filter(function(e){return e;}).reduce(function(a,v){ if(v){return a+1;} },0);
      if(rc>mcpr){e.range.setValue("FALSE");e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr);};
      let cc=avs.map(function(r,i){return r[e.range.columnStart-ulc];}).filter(function(e){return e}).reduce(function(a,v){if(v){return a+1;}},0);
      if(cc>mcpc){e.range.setValue('FALSE');e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc);};          
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cooper! I saved your code on my Google Sheet under `Code4.gs` script.  When running, I got the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code4")`.  Is there anything I am doing wrong? The sheet name (line 3 in your code) is `Sheet1`, and the range of values (line 6 in your code) is `D3:AC7`. My Google Sheet again: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_a6jA01Sz0bjTvQXh_S47qTFXfb0qV8KlTXgOGr6nU/)

Comment: If you trying to run this function from the script editor.  That won't work.  The function requires the event obj.  The e parameter gets filled with the event object when an onEdit trigger is generated by editing a cell in the page you entered

Comment: Oh I see! Now it is working from the main sheet. Lot of things to learn still... THANK YOU @Cooper!

Comment: I put up an example for your specific case. I wrote it so that you can move the array anywhere but I suspect that your array may be pretty large for it.  If you enter data to fast it may not be able to keep up.